# How to find root of "Could not find or load main class" error when running JAR

Tags: java, jar

I have seen this question asked so many times, but there was no precise answer to my problem. My story is simple - I downloaded a legitimate JAR file, for a functioning and advertised application, from here: https://github.com/kamilfb/mqtt-spy/wiki/Downloads.

The application brings the obvious instruction to start it as `java -jar mqtt-spy-0.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` but that results in the well known error, being in my case `Error: Could not find or load main class pl.baczkowicz.mqttspy.Main`

My system is Ubuntu 15.04, Java version is
`openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)`

I don't have another computer to test it elsewhere. I did some checks and the JAR file looks pretty much normal. I even tried de-compressing it and running the class directly, it won't budge, same error message. I tried some online .class analysis tools, nothing caught my attention. Also I reviewed about a dozen of pages referring to "Could not find or load" problem. No luck so far.

Not sure if anyone bothers, but I did my Java Programmers certification with Sun yet in 2005... and I feel frustrated now. While I hope there is an easy solution for my problem, e.g. some nice Ubuntu issue ;-), I am ready to dig deeper, and looking for any hints that would guide me to finding the root cause of  this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean).

Comment: Anyway lets start from beginning. Did you check MANIFEST in the JAR file? Which class does it point as main-class? Based on error message it may look like it is `pl.baczkowicz.mqttspy.Main`. Does your Jar contain `pl/baczkowicz/mqttspy/Main.class` structure?

Comment: I've downloaded the latest version (0.2.0) and works with no problems in my machine. Using HotSpot 1.8.0_45.

Comment: Luiggi - thanks! At least that gives me some hope :)
Pshemo - In manifest: Main-Class: pl.baczkowicz.mqttspy.Main, after unpacking the jar i get to see the class file is there:
`nathan@nthlx:~/mqtt-spy$ ls pl/baczkowicz/mqttspy/

application.css  connectivity  logger      scripts  tasks      utils
common           events        Main.class  stats    testcases  versions
configuration    exceptions    messages    storage  ui         xml`

Comment: After Luiggi's comment if you wouldn't have this structure and manifest it would simply mean you didn't download same file. Actually maybe it is worth checking if your file is not corrupted, so that Main.class couldn't be loaded properly. Did you try redownloading this jar, or downloading it from different location?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I downloaded the file using another link (there are 2 distinct on the page) and I get the same result. Also, if my download would be corrupted, I would probably get an error while extracting the contents of JAR file.

Comment: For all the friendly people out there - Yes, I have also tried re-booting my computer ;)

Comment: Damn it. That was my next question https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0. Anyway since I am not working on Ubuntu and don't have it installed I can't help you more with testing what went wrong. Sorry. For now try using `java -cp yourJar pl.baczkowicz.mqttspy.Main` and see if it helps.

Comment: I have tried this option already. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you it was very helpful for me. I had exactly the same problem, and looking [the solution here as well](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)

My fix was:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update
```

then, install the JDK Oracle 8

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and then, checking java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It is displayed between other choices:

```
 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1082 
     auto mode
......
```

Press  to keep the current choice`[*]`, or type selection number:

I keep the 0 current choice `[*]`

then, running mqttspy worked just fine :-)

```
java -jar mqtt-spy-0.5.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

Additionally install Java FX, since this is required and worked for me (Ubuntu 16: package openfx):

```
apt install openjfx
```

See also this issue:
https://github.com/kamilfb/mqtt-spy/issues/88

I currently successfully run it on openjdk version "1.8.0_121" here.

Comment: installing `openjfx` fixed this problem with proper version of java installed in advance

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked in my case was to use HotSpot Java 8, from Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you have multiple java versions, you can run the jar file by giving the java file path as well.

```
brew install --cask liberica-jdk@17-full
brew install --cask liberica-jdk17-full
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-17-full.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar mqtt-spy-1.0.1-beta-b18-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```